# How to fix this code to read this file in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's my code, which should be able to read the file, but it gives me this:

> Error: Invalid format in file

What's wrong in this code?

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> routes;
    print_rasse();
    std::string inp;
    std::cout << "Give a name for input file: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, inp);
    std::ifstream file(inp);
    std::string row;
    if ( not file ) {
        std::cout << "Error: File could not be read." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(getline(file, row)){
        if (count(row.begin(), row.end(),';'+!1)){
            std::cout << "Error: Invalid format in file." << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

The `.txt` file which I'm trying to read contains this:

```
West;Pyynikintori;0
West;Tuulensuu;0.5
West;Keskustori;1.5
West;Koskipuisto;1.8
West;Rautatieasema;2.2
West;Tulli;2.5
West;Sammonaukio;2.8
East;Sammonaukio;
East;Kaleva;0.2
East;Uintikeskus;0.3
East;Kalevanrinne;0.6
East;Hakametsa;1
East;Turtola;3
East;Hallila;5
East;Hervanta;7
East;Hervannan kampus;7.1
South;Hervannan kampus
South;Etela-Hervanta;0.4
South;Hervantajarvi;0.7
Hospital;Sammonaukio
Hospital;Kalevan kirkko;0.1
Hospital;Hippos;0.4
Hospital;TAYS;0.6
Hospital;Kaupin kampus;0.7
```

Comment: What should `';'+!1` be? Can you elaborate about that please?

Comment: `not`? What's wrong with your C++ compiler?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  that would be just `';'` (ie `';' + 0`, but he's trying to look "cool". While not being able to read a file.

Comment: @Blindy It's an [alternative operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

Comment: `if (count(row.begin(), row.end(),';'+!1))` will succeed if there are any semicolons in the line.  And all of your lines have semicolons.  Did you mean `if (count(row.begin(), row.end(), ';') != 2)`?

Comment: Hey, Im trying to make this "Error: Invalid format in file" to be printed when there is something more than three parts of text which is separated by ';'.

Comment: @Blindy Yeah sure. More like obfuscating what it's actually doing. I'd not expect to find a line which doesn't contain a `';'` in a semicolon delimited CSV file :-P

Comment: @Peter85 So you probably want to check, if the result of `count()` is not equal 2?

Comment: Okay, how to change it if I want this error to succeed only if there is something more than three parts of text separated with ;?

Comment: @Peter85 see my answer

Comment: So it should read this file with those semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

In this statement:

`if (count(row.begin(), row.end(),';'+!1))`

`!1` is effectively the same as `0`, so `';'+0` is just `';'`. The statement is effectively this:

`if (count(row.begin(), row.end(), ';'))`

It is counting the number of `;` characters in the `row`.  An integer implicitly converts to a `bool`, where `0` is `false` and non-`0` is `true`.  So, if there are any matching characters in the `row`, the `if` will evaluate as `true`, otherwise as `false`.

Since each line in the `.txt` file shown has 2 `;` characters in it, `count()` will return 2, thus the `if` will be `true`, and so the code will display the error message.

You probably meant to do this instead:

`if (count(row.begin(), row.end(), ';') != 2)`